# How to check in functions.php if there is data in a WP_Query?

Tags: posts, functions, wp-query, actions, query-posts

I have 2 different WP Query on the home page.
I need to check $home_query condition in functions.php then I want to do something if $home_query returns null.
I tried with pre_get_posts action I couldn't catch $home_query data and it's worked twice, because have two WP_Query on the page.

Using pagination by If $home_query returns null, I want to redirect the page to 404 page and get 404 responded code.

For example, https://example.com/page/200/ Page number is 200 but in the page there is no have 200 page number, I want to redirect 404 page and get 404 response instead of "show no result text"

index.php

```
$home_query = new WP_Query( array('posts_per_page' => get_query_var('posts_per_page'),'paged' => $current_page ) );


$featured_post = new WP_Query(array('p'=>get_theme_mod('featured-content-callout-post'),'order' => 'DESC','posts_per_page'=> 1));


            if($home_query->have_posts()):
                    while ($home_query->have_posts()):
                        $home_query->the_post();
                        get_template_part('template-parts/content','list');
                    endwhile;
            else;
                   // get_template_part('template-parts/content','none');
                      // I tried to use redirect code in here but I couldn't.
            endif;
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: `pre_get_posts` happens _before_ a query runs, so it's too early. You can't know if the query had results or not until it's ran

Comment: Hmm which one I have to use ?

Comment: It's unclear what you're actually trying to achieve, can you explain the original problem that you're trying to solve requires this?

Comment: Using pagination by If $home_query returns null, I want to redirect the page to 404 page and get 404 responded code.

For example, https://example.com/page/200/ Page number is 200 but on the page there is no have 200 page number, I want to redirect  404 page and get 404 response instead of "show no result text"

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the query returned any posts by doing `$home_query->have_posts()`.

```php
$home_query = new WP_Query( array('posts_per_page' => get_query_var('posts_per_page'),'paged' => $current_page ) );
if( !$home_query->have_posts() ){
   // Do this if $home_query had no posts.
}
```

Comment: Yes,  but I need to do it in functions.php. If there is no have post, I have to get 404 response code and redirect

Comment: If that's your goal then you do not need to do this, this is the wrong approach. You should instead of asked _"How do I redirect the browser if no posts are found in the main query and we are on the homepage?"_. That question has a much easier answer. You can't both redirect and 404 as a redirect uses a different HTTP status code. What you want is possible, but the solution to this question is not going to give you what you want. You should ask how to fix your problem, not how to build a specific solution, [you fell into the  X Y problem trap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Answer (score 0):

You can use two hooks to achieve the desired result:

1. Use the `parse_query` action hook (the query variables are initialised in this hook) to create the `$home_query` and place the results in the WP cache using the `wp_cache_set` function (content in the cache is only stored for the current request).
2. Use the `template_redirect` action hook to fetch the contents from the cache, using `wp_cache_get` function and see if there are results or not. From here you can redirect to some other page. Please check the hook docs and the examples at the bottom of this page: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_redirect/

Here is an example code:

```php
function custom_parse_query() {
    $home_query = new WP_Query( array('posts_per_page' => get_query_var('posts_per_page'), 'paged' => get_query_var('page') ) );
    wp_cache_set('home_query', $home_query);
}
add_action( 'parse_query', 'custom_parse_query' );

function custom_template_redirect() {

    $home_query = wp_cache_get('home_query');

    if( $home_query instanceof WP_Query && ! $home_query->have_posts() ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url( '/signup/' ) );
        exit();
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'custom_template_redirect' );
```

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your answer. When I use WP_Query with an argument I getting a limit error. Without arguments it's working. Do you have an idea? Thank you
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 792723456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in //blog/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php on line 584

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 792723456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /blog/wp-includes/class-wp-fatal-error-handler.php on line 72